# Dynamic Conversion of XML to JSON

Tags: java, xml, json

Is there any way (with Java code examples, if possible) to convert, on the fly, an `XML` input to `JSON`, without any knowledge of the actual contents and the structure of the XML source (file, string, etc.)?

Say, for instance, that one has a very large XML dataset with unknown structure and multiple nesting levels, stored to a big text file. Reading everything into memory is not possible (for lack of space) and they want to convert this into `JSON` directly, i.e., without having to write any code to detect and handle the StAX tags (e.g., `START_ELEMENT`, `CHARACTERS`, `END_ELEMENT`).

The ideal solution would be to get a `Reader` or `InputStream` from the converter, so that, for instance, one supplies the XML file and the `Reader` or `InputStream` produces `JSON`, to be fed to a FileOutputStream, or even directly to a `JSON` parser like `Jackson`. If that is not possible, at least a way of progressively reading an XML file, converting to JSON and writing to another file would be an acceptable compromise.

Tools that can be used for converting from/to XML/JSON (e.g., [StaxON](http://beckchr.github.com/staxon/), [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/), [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org), [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)) do not seem to do that but only conversion of a known structure.

**EDIT:** Getting a `Reader` or `InputStream` from an OutputStream or a Writer (which would also cover the "conversion" I spoke of above), can be done in a number of ways, although for best results and "infinite" input sizes multithreading is involved. Solutions are described in this [article in Ostermiller.org](http://ostermiller.org/convert_java_writer_reader.html) and a similar implementation can be found in the [IO-Tools library](http://io-tools.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a trivial example using Java's built-in StAX implementation to [parse XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html#bnbfb) and Jettison to [produce JSON](http://jettison.codehaus.org/User%27s+Guide#User%27sGuide-STaX) from it. The [XMLEventWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.html) has a convenient [`add(XMLEventWriter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.html#add%28javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader%29) method for bridging a reader to a writer, making this super-simple:

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLOutputFactory;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml =
            "<root><foo>foo string</foo><bar><x>1</x><y>5</y></bar></root>";
        XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
            .createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xml));
        XMLEventWriter writer = new MappedXMLOutputFactory(new HashMap())
            .createXMLEventWriter(System.out);
        writer.add(reader);
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

I've created a self-contained Maven project demonstrating this [on Github](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/stackoverflow/8367671-convert-xml-stream-to-json-stream).

Comment: This provides the "write to file" (or to the standard output) solution. Thanks for the answer and the extra effort!

Comment: How do you ignore comment tags with this ? XMLEventWriter throws exceptions when there are comment tags in the xml.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun: That should be its own question, complete with sample code, not a comment on a 1.5-year-old answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have created a question before posting this message as I figured you'd say that. Any help is appreciated.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428574/converting-xml-to-json-using-jettison

Comment: First getting IllegalStateException on xmlns="...". Second, after removing the xmlns, getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with StAXON, see https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Converting-XML-to-JSON for sample code.

Comment: Apparently you can write to a file but there is no direct way to "pipe" the JSON output into a reader or InputStream. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with static methods fromXml and toJson. I am the maintainer of the project.

Code example:

```
import com.github.underscore.U;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class StringTest {

    @Test
    public void toJsonFromXml() {
        final String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<root>\n"
            + "  <FirstItem>1</FirstItem>\n  <SecondItem>2</SecondItem>\n</root>";
        assertEquals("{\n"
            + "  \"root\": {\n"
            + "    \"FirstItem\": \"1\",\n"
            + "    \"SecondItem\": \"2\"\n"
            + "  }\n"
            + "}",
            U.toJson((Map<String, Object>) U.fromXml(xml)));
    }
}
```